# How to change NavigationPage bar background color dynamically

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have seem many examples on how to change the navigation page but none work for me.

All the other stackoverflow links that I have visited on this subject dont work!

I have the following in my app.xaml

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#ff5733"/>
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

this is fine and works.however I would like to change the color in code when a particular page is loaded.

I have tried few things like in the viewmodel of a page

```
 var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
```

but navigationPage is always null??

Dont think it matters but I am using prism.

Is there an working examples somewhere?

many thanks

Comment: Navigate to your page like this:  
NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(NavigationPage) + "/" + nameof(YourPage));

Comment: You can first try out this one in On appearing method of your xaml.cs page or else if not working then in constructor of your xaml.cs page:
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.OrangeRed;
This may change navigation bar color on loading of the page.

Comment: @AlmirVuk hi do not understand how what you suggested should change the background color of the navigation page.Am I missing something?

Comment: @MShah just tried both and casting to a navigationPage I get InvalidCastException. My main page is a MasterDetailPage

Comment: You can refer this one for better understanding, it's providing the way to change the color for master detail page as well:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95943/how-to-change-navigation-bar-background-color-for-each-content-page.